# How to reduce ticks?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have 250 rows of data, it starts january 2002 and ends septemper 2022 and interwal per row is one row/one month of the year.

[image]

Now i want to plot it but it takes all 250 rows and plot it and i only want like one year shown per tick

The y axis is float and x axis is string

I have saw that you have to label them manualy but what if i have like realy big data? There must be some efficient way.

i have tried something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = df_polt['Päivä']
y = df_polt['Diesel']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(15, 10)) 
ax.plot(X, y)
```

I want that X axis is like 10 ticks

[image]

Comment: I suggest that, when you're representing a growth, you make your _y_-axis starting from zero.

Comment: Unless you want to mislead the viewer, of course.

Comment: All those ticks come from the fact that the x-axis data type is string. You need to convert, in this case, to some sort of date.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you used xticks you'll be fine
https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html

```
plt.xticks([0, 365, 730], ['2001', '2002', '2003'],rotation=0)
```

An approach like this one is what I propose, you can always customize and/or make it automatic.

edit: I assumed that you have data for each day (this affects the points where you  add a tick, change it according to your dataset).

Answer (score 0):

Untested.

```
plt.plot(df_polt['Diesel'])
plt.xticks(range(0,241,24))
plt.xticklabels(["%d-01"%y for year in range(2002,2023,2)])
```